# Django: Filtering on annotated value with gte integer results into comparison with True in SQL

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to make QuerySet in Django which restricts teams to only those which have more than two active members. I have following UserProfile class in my models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(
      User,
      related_name='userprofile',
      unique=True,
      null=False,
      blank=False,
      )
   team = models.ForeignKey(
      Team,
      related_name='users',
      verbose_name=_(u"Tým"),
      null=False, blank=False)
...
```

The query is following:

```
Team.annotate(team_member_count=Sum('users__user__is_active')).filter(team_member_count__gte = 2)
```

The problem is, that it results to SQL query where is True instead of value 2:

```
SELECT `dpnk_team`.`id`, `dpnk_team`.`name`, `dpnk_team`.`subsidiary_id`, `dpnk_team`.`coordinator_id`, `dpnk_team`.`invitation_token`, 
SUM(`auth_user`.`is_active`) AS `team_member_count` 
FROM `dpnk_team` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `dpnk_userprofile` T4 ON (`dpnk_team`.`id` = T4.`team_id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `auth_user` ON (T4.`user_id` = `auth_user`.`id`) 
GROUP BY `dpnk_team`.`id` 
HAVING SUM(`auth_user`.`is_active`) >= True
ORDER BY `dpnk_team`.`name` ASC
```

Which is giving also teams with only 1 active member (True evaluates as 1). Although the "is_active" field is defined as boolean, the "team_member_count" evaluates to integer value, so I expect it to be tested as integer further.

I am using MySQL database and tried it with Django 1.4.3 and 1.5.1.

Am I missing something and should I write the query differently, or is this a Django bug?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it *is* a bug in django. The workaround is:

```
 (Team.objects.filter(users__user__is_active=True)
              .annotate(team_member_count=Count('users'))
              .filter(team_member_count__gte=1))
```